# Google tag manager button reference

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get google tag manager to track a couple of different buttons on a site. We're currently unable to change the site to aid with this, so we have to find a solution solely with tag manager.

There are several buttons on the site all with the same format as to the two below.. they all have "submit" as the type and a unique term for value so I'm trying to use the tag manager Form Listener which picks up on type="submit". Is there any variable I can use to pull the value field into my event so I can create individual goals in analytics?

etc etc

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to google tag manager setup and not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in variable "Click Element", then create custom JS-variable:

```
function(){
 try{
   return {{element}}.getAttribute("value"); //I am not sure now if it is {{element}} or {{Click Element}}
 }catch(err){}
}
```

This will give you a value attribute of clicked button.

Maybe a useful link by Simo Ahava:

http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/#3

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in auto-event variable Element Attribute to get value. And be sure to use click tracking and not form tracking, because you want to track button clicks and not form submissions.